# SSIS Suddenly NULL in StagingkeyID cannot fill factsheet

Tags: sql-server, ssis

My Factsheet build at the moment [image: Factsheet]

Yesterday when i executed this it was all fine. All rows were filled.
When i run it now it gets stuck at `LKP - Salesperson Key and LKP - Stock Item Key.` every row will go to the Lookup No Match Output.

when i ignore the failure it will give me back this Error:

> Information: 0x400490F4 at DFT - Sales - Source - Staging, LKP -
> Salesperson Key [77]: LKP - Salesperson Key has cached 0 rows
>
> Information: 0x400490F5 at DFT - Sales - Source - Staging, LKP -
> Salesperson Key [77]: LKP - Salesperson Key has cached a total of 0 rows.
>
> Information: 0x40209340 at DFT - Sales - Source - Staging, LKP -
> Salesperson Key [77]: The number of unique rows added to the cache is 0.
>
> Information: 0x402090E2 at DFT - Sales - Source - Staging, LKP - Salesperson >Key [77]: The LKP - Salesperson Key processed 0 rows in the cache. The >processing time was 0.001 seconds. The cache used 0 bytes of memory.
>
> Information: 0x400490F4 at DFT - Sales - Source -
> Staging, LKP - Stock Item Key [102]: LKP - Stock Item Key has cached 0
> rows.
>
> Information: 0x400490F5 at DFT - Sales - Source - Staging, LKP -
> Stock Item Key [102]: LKP - Stock Item Key has cached a total of 0
> rows.
>
> Information: 0x40209340 at DFT - Sales - Source - Staging, LKP -
> Stock Item Key [102]: The number of unique rows added to the cache is
> 0.
>
> Information: 0x402090E2 at DFT - Sales - Source - Staging, LKP - Stock Item Key >[102]: The LKP - Stock Item Key processed 0 rows in the cache. The processing >time was 0.015 seconds. The cache used 0 bytes of memory.
>
> Error: 0x0 at SQL Merge Staging - Fact: Cannot insert the value NULL into >column 'Stock Item Key', table 'WideWorldImportersDW.Fact.Sale';
> column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails. Error: 0xC002F210 at SQL
> Merge Staging - Fact, Execute SQL Task: Executing the query "MERGE
> [Fact].[Sale] AS TARGET

This is not possible because the keys are staging keys, these Keys always has a number because it is a generated ID.

Data is from the WWI(World Wide Importers) database.

I can give you more information when needed.

**Update:** [image: Mapping]
**Update 1:** Employee package mapping[image: employee]

Comment: Throw a data viewer before salesperson key and look at the data. and then manually confirm that some of the records are in the lookup table

Comment: Also, confirm you LKP queries are accurate.

Comment: i looked at the data viewer and i can see that they are all filled with a number there are no NULL to be found. i will place my mapping in a update

Comment: does the lookup query return values and are the sales person ids in there

Comment: yes that is the weird thing